# Enabling Data Interoperabilty Extension in ArcGIS Pro with Esri Evaluation Account?

Tags: installation, arcgis-pro, data-interoperability

I just created an Esri evaluation account to test the ArcGIS Data Interoperability extension in ArcGIS Pro, I assigned the extension in ArcGIS Online to an account. But I can not get access in ArcGIS Pro.

How to enable the Data Interoperability extension in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: In ArcPro the tool is present. Just go to Insert->connections->and add a WFS connection. Then paste in the url to the WFS, and if its authenticated then entered the credentials. The WFS connection was not present in Arc Desktop without a separate install. See here -- https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/data-interoperability/what-is-the-data-interoperability-extension.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you are ArcGIS Pro license through your organization (with Named User) confirm that Data Interop licenses is checked [image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes I found the solution, I did not install the Data Interoperability extension. So after installation the problem is solved.